# Twilio: Received an 'hangup' event warning

Tags: twilio

Salutations, community.
I have what I think is rather simple question to twilio experts.

I have a flow, which starts with an API call and proceeds as follows:

1. Make outgoing call
2. Split based on ... (call status)
3. Run function

I notice periodic warnings in the Debugger with the following content:

Received an 'hangup' event while processing the 'Ended' widget for Execution Sid -X- and Flow Sid -Y-. Ignoring this event and not transitioning to another widget.

Below there are couple of causes and resolutions, which led me to believe that the issue in my particular scenario could be that 'An event came in while processing a widget that cannot handle that event (e.g. incoming message received during Run Function widget)'. Possible solutions prescribe that I must 'Return results for Function calls and HTTP requests quickly', but since the function call happens after the outgoing call, it doesn't seem I can always return from the function before this call ends and the 'hungup' event occurs.

Would love to hear ideas. While this behaviour doesn't cause any issues, seeing this erroneous (-ish) behaviour makes my eye twitch a bit.

Thanks.

Comment: I've been a similar problem - I'll open up another question and see if we get an answer on it.